# Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pivot table that has the indexes listed in each row. Currently, I have them only appearing in the first instance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
df
     A    B      C  D  E
0  foo  one  small  1  2
1  foo  one  large  2  4
2  foo  one  large  2  5
3  foo  two  small  3  5
4  foo  two  small  3  6
5  bar  one  large  4  6
6  bar  one  small  5  8
7  bar  two  small  6  9
8  bar  two  large  7  9
```

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
table
C        large  small
A   B
bar one    4.0    5.0
    two    7.0    6.0
foo one    4.0    1.0
    two    NaN    6.0
```

I would like for  `foo` and `bar` to appear in the 2nd and 4th lines respectively so that all rows have a values.

Comment: I think that's just how Pandas displays mult-level indexes. `table.index` will show the full index. `table.loc[('bar', 'two'), 'large']` returns 7.0 as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a by-product of the display mechanism for `MultiIndex` data.
Use `table.reset_index()` to move the index back into columns, and you will see all the columns being displayed with all values.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)
:
[image]

So you can do:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(table)

C        large  small
A   B                
bar one    4.0    5.0
bar two    7.0    6.0
foo one    4.0    1.0
foo two    NaN    6.0
```